# When I select restart, my Ubuntu screen goes black but doesnt power off (similar for power off)

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop last night and notice that when I select restart it goes into an unresponsive black screen with a small white cursor at the top left. If I select power off, I get a black screen with the Dell and Ubunto logo but nothing happens.
I unstalled Ubuntu as a dual boot with Windows 11 home where I partitioned the drive to be 550G for windows and 350G for Linux.

Other than this the Linux OS appears to be operating fine with what Ive done with it so far. Just now I need to manually power off by holding down the power button for 10s (dont see this as being a very good long term solution).

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu so no idea where to start debugging this.

My laptop details are as follows:
Model:
Dell Inspiron 16 7620
CPU:
Intel Core i7-1260P
4 x 2.10 GHz (P-Core), 8 x 1.50 GHz (E-Core)

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks,
Diarmuid